# pymongo create_index doesn't create index

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to create a MongoDB index in pymongo with:

```
xml_db.create_index([("source", pymongo.DESCENDING),("active", pymongo.DESCENDING)], background=True, name="daily_index")
```

It executes successfully. But when I do `print(xml_db.index_information())`, I can't see the `daily_index`.

what is the case here?

N.B. I have removed an index with the same name just before creating the index.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct. See if you can get this to work:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, DESCENDING

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
xml_db = db.xml_db

xml_db.create_index([("source", DESCENDING),("active", DESCENDING)], background=True, name="daily_index")

print(xml_db.index_information())
```

prints:

```
{'_id_': {'v': 2, 'key': [('_id', 1)], 'ns': 'mydatabase.xml_db'}, 'daily_index': {'v': 2, 'key': [('source', -1), ('active', -1)], 'ns': 'mydatabase.xml_db', 'background': True}}
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing. I used the same function to create index many times. Now suddenly the function doesn't work. It does execute, but when I print index_information, it doesn't show up. Also, the queries are terribly slow, which certainly means, the index are not created. 

One thing I was doing is, creating index and removing documents from the same DB at the same time. Can it cause any problem?

Comment: Try it on a fresh database; if it works it sounds like your MongoDB instance might need some maintenance (restart / repair etc.)